# Unable to create service "Only one Looper may be created per thread"

Tags: android, service

I'm developing an Android 3.1 Tablet application.

This app will run a thread. On its **service** I have this code:

```
public class UDPSocketBackgroundService extends Service
{

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    Log.v(TAG, "in onCreate()");

    // xxxxxx
    Looper.prepare();
    mServiceHandler = new Handler() {
        /**
         * 
         */
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            DatagramPacket packet = (DatagramPacket) msg.obj;
            //String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());

            Message backMsg = Message.obtain();
            backMsg.arg1 = Activity.RESULT_OK;;

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putByteArray("CLIENT_DATA", packet.getData());
            bundle.putString("CLIENT_HOST", packet.getAddress().getHostAddress());
            bundle.putString("CLIENT_PORT", new Integer(packet.getPort()).toString());
            backMsg.setData(bundle);

            try
            {
                outMessenger.send(backMsg);
            }
            catch (android.os.RemoteException e1)
            {
                Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Exception sending message", e1);
            }
        }
    };
    Looper.loop();
}
```

But I don't know why (because it is my first time with services) I get an exception here:

```
Looper.prepare();
```

**UPDATE**

**Service's onBind event:**

```
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    // Get messager from the Activity
    if (extras != null) {
        outMessenger = (Messenger) extras.get("MESSENGER");
    }

    try
    {
        myThread = new UDPServerThread("X", 8888, mServiceHandler);
        myThread.start();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mMessenger.getBinder();
}
```

This how I start the service from main **activity**:

```
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = null;
    intent = new Intent(this, UDPSocketBackgroundService.class);
    // Create a new Messenger for the communication back
    // From the Service to the Activity
    Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler);
    intent.putExtra("MESSENGER", messenger);

    bindService(intent, conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Service **doesn't run on Background thread**, but on the Dedicated UI thread.

**2.** It was considered good practice to have UI work on UI thread, and Non-UI work on Non-UI thread, but **from HoneyComb it became a rule**.

**3.** So for your background thread use Thread will Handler, or AsyncTask.

**4.** Non-UI work are executed on the foreground using Handler, which in turn **requires UI thread to call Looper.loop() to get the actual messages serviced**, So there is **no need to explicitly call** Looper.loop() or prepare().

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean with "Thread will Handler"?

Comment: I have updated my question adding how I start the service. I don't know if this is important for your answer but I think I must say you.

Comment: When its needed that the Service must be binded with the Activity, then  i use `public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)` , else i do everything in onCreate() , onStart or onStartCommand and onDestroy()

Answer (score 1):

A service runs on the UI thread and a the UI thread already has a looper which is why you are getting that error.

If you intented to do your work in a background thread then you might need to create a new thread for that code you want to run.

Maybe you could look into [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question adding how I start the service. I don't know if this is important for your answer but I think I must say you.

Answer (score 1):

First, `Service` doesn't run on a background thread so you should use either a `Thread`, an `AsyncTask` or an `IntentService` for your background work. Second, `Service` already has a Looper initialized, you have to remove `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()` from your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question adding how I start the service. I don't know if this is important for your answer but I think I must say you.

Comment: Try extending `IntentService` instead of `Service` and add your background logic to the `onHandleIntent(...)` method. You don't have to bind your service to your activity you can just simply use `startService(...)` with the approrpiate intent. If you want to post back changes to the UI thread you can use handlers. But the best practice would be for you to use `AsyncTask` instead of services in this case.

Comment: I bind my service because I want to use messenger to communicate from activity to service and reversal.

Comment: You can use the `AsyncTask`'s `onPreExecute(...)`, `onPostExecute(...)` and `onProgressUpdate(...)` methods to communicate with the UI thread, I think you should give it a try.

Comment: I run an UDP Server and I think an AsyncTask it is not prepare for that. See my other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977729/communicate-worker-thread-with-main-thread, answers.

Comment: I think in that case you should just leave out the service part, and create your worker `Thread` and your `Handler` in your activity and use them to post back messages to the UI thread. As far as I can tell you only need the UDP server while your application is running, right? In that case this would be easier.

Comment: I will need communication from activity to thread, and from thread to activity. Can I do that with a thread with a handler?

Comment: Yes. You can implement the `handleMessage()` method of your handler in your activity, and you can use that `Handler` from your thread to post messages back to the activity.